# Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String

Tags: java, android

am trying to add a library called smooth check box while I trying to cast it it showed me an error Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String '
this is my Class
............................................................................

```
package abtech.waiteriano.com.retrievingcontactsexample;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import cn.refactor.library.SmoothCheckBox;

/**
 * Created by Trinity Tuts on 10-01-2015.
 */
public class SelectUserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public List<SelectUser> _data;
    private ArrayList<SelectUser> arraylist;
    Context _c;
    ViewHolder v;

    public SelectUserAdapter(List<SelectUser> selectUsers, Context context) {
        _data = selectUsers;
        _c = context;
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(_data);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return _data.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, null);
            Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view1");
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view2");
        }

        v = new ViewHolder();

        v.check = (SmoothCheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.contactsCB);

        final SelectUser data = (SelectUser) _data.get(i);
        v.check.setText(data.getName());
        v.check.setChecked(data.getCheckedBox());;


        Log.e("Image Thumb", "--------------" + data.getThumb());

        /*// Set check box listener android
        v.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    data.setCheckedBox(true);
                  } else {
                    data.setCheckedBox(false);
                }
            }
        });*/

        view.setTag(data);
        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        _data.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            _data.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (SelectUser wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    _data.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        SmoothCheckBox check;
    }
}
```

and the error in this line

```
v.check.setText(data.getName());
```

android Monitor Error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
E:\AndroidWorkSpace\RetrievingContactsExample\app\src\main\java\abtech\waiteriano\com\retrievingcontactsexample\SelectUserAdapter.java
Error:(69, 16) error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.206 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

............................................................................
I don't know how to solve this error it's ma pleasure if any could help me 
sorry of any thing is not clear I hope this gonna be understandable
............................................................................

Comment: If you have issues compiling your code please **always** include the Compiler error. A quick look in the mentioned `SmoothCheckBox`-implementation shows that there is no `setText(...)` method.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for replying me I eddtited my question have a check please

Comment: Seems like SmoothCheckBox does not have such setText(String) method.

Comment: @Jonathan Aste Yeah I think I should create a text view behind the check box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean [this `SmoothCheckBox` on github](https://github.com/andyxialm/SmoothCheckBox).

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/andyxialm/SmoothCheckBox/blob/master/library/src/main/java/cn/refactor/library/SmoothCheckBox.java), one finds no `setText(String)`-method. If I understand the readme correctly, those check boxes are designed to have a selected and unselected color, but no text.